# trouble deploying .WAR to tomcat

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, netbeans-6.9, tomcat7

im having trouble deploying a war file on tomcat.

i have written a webapp in netbeans on my windows machine. it all runs fine. what i want to do is deploy the application on my linux computer that is acting as my server. once the application is built, i copy the war file from the dist folder in my project directory onto a pendrive. i then copy this onto the desktop of my linux computer.

i then start tomcat and using the application manager i browse the war file to deploy, then click deploy. i get a message at the top of the browser saying 'OK'. yet if i look at my tomcat output in the terminal window i have the following error:

```
4/01/2011 5:09:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive Kingdoms.war
4/01/2011 5:09:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig init
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/Kingdoms] 
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:72)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:48)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:70)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:706)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:570)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:891)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1467)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:561)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
4/01/2011 5:09:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : invalid CEN header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4657)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4815)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:570)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:891)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1467)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:561)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
4/01/2011 5:09:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
4/01/2011 5:09:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
4/01/2011 5:09:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Kingdoms] startup failed due to previous errors
```

also i can now see in the applications list, my app. i click start in the commands for the app but get a message at the top of the screen saying 'FAIL - Application at context path /Kingdoms could not be started'

what am i doing wrong? how to fix this?

Comment: In my case I was doing a `jar xvf` to extract a file, update it, then update the WAR. But I was doing it from a folder above as described in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-104 - once I changed my working directory to where the WAR is located, I resolved the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the war archive is corrupt or invalid.

check that the war generation procedure is not failing and that the war file is a valid zip file prior to copying to your pen drive etc.

if you're on windows you can do this by changing the file extension to .zip and opening with a zip program such as winzip or winrar.

if you're on another operating system you probably don't need to change the extension.

if the war is a valid zip it's probably being corrupted as a result of your transfer process ie going onto or from your pen drive.

Comment: i found a file in the lib folder that wouldnt budge. also i think the pendrive doesnt like war files, tried another one and it worked. random. thanks

Comment: you could accept one of the answers since they are both right.

Comment: Ran into this with eclipse, recreating the project was the only remedy I could find, despite all project files appearing to be correct and multiple clean / build passes.

Answer (score 14):

It could be a file protection issue, which you can fix by issuing something like:
chmod 755 webapp.war

it happened to me that my sftp would just slap a 700 on the file transferred, causing that error.

Answer (score 10):

This might be due to one of the following reasons.

- Corrupted WAR file
- Corrupted JAR files under WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: i found a file in the lib folder that wouldnt budge. also i think the pendrive doesnt like war files, tried another one and it worked. random. thanks

Answer (score 3):

First thing to check is if you have free space on your disk. If your partition is 100% full, then it will be impossible to extract the .WAR file.

Answer (score 2):

have same error - with war all ok, restarting Tomcat resolve problem
so i think it's becouse Tomcat start deploy war before it fully uploaded

Comment: ah that would make alot of sense. if the file was large and you were copying it directly to the tomcat container. i think that would explain the problem i had. wow this was ages ago haha

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and rebuilding/uploading the war was NOT fixing the problem. What I ended up doing to fix it was uploading the war under a different name, then renaming the war once it had successfully deployed. A bit bizarre that this would work, but it was a better solution for me than restarting tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

also possibly because of an incorrect entry in solr.xml
It must point to where the .war file is located.

Answer (score 0):

Also look out for file permissions of the .war file you have deployed. For me that was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the manifest file.

```
Class-Path:
```

should followed by a whitespace.