# Doc Base must point to a war file

Tags: tomcat7

I have created a war file. When I am trying to deploy it on my local tomcat instance , its up and running properly.

When I am trying to deploy it one of the server , I am getting the below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Doc base must point to a WAR file
```

On searching I found that the very reason of this issue is the corrupted war. But I am wondering that if the war is corrupted then why it is up and running at my local instance.

Any hint would be a great help.

Comment: Do you have a context.xml file in your war's META-INF directory ? If so can you paste it here

Comment: possible solutions -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590614/trouble-deploying-war-to-tomcat & http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201302.mbox/%3CCAO5arLPPDT2YBH6cRkfGcGjJrY_fEmvtOdqH08_4Dj76DQrV0w@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: there is no context.xml file